# Where does the data go from the cropper API in drupal 8 and how do you access it?

Tags: twig, drupal-8, drupal-theming

Within the user's profile, I'm utilizing the cropper api to get the user's image cropped. However, I'm not sure how I am able to obtain that image.

I'm currently attempting to retrieve the image in two places:

1. The site's header (through my `.theme` file for the `account--menu.html.twig` file).
2. In the groups module

For the header, originally I would retrieve the original image through this line of code:

```
function kropotkin_preprocess_menu__account(&$variables)
{

$uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();

if($uid > 0)
{
    $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($uid);

    if (!$user->user_picture->isEmpty()) {
      $picture = file_create_url($user->user_picture->entity->getFileUri());
    }else{
      $picture = 'nothing here';
    }

    // Set variables
    $variables['comradery'] = [
        'profile_picture' => $picture
    ];
}
}
```

This is retrieving the original (uncropped) image into the header. The crop type machine name is `profile_picture` I have tried `$user->profile_picture->entity->getFileUri()` but it returned null.

Within the group's module I already have images being displayed properly (again uncropped images) like so:

```
{% for contributor, child in content.field_project_contributor if contributor|first != '#' %}
                        <a href="{{ path('entity.user.canonical', {'user': child["#options"].entity.id}) }}" class="mr-_5">
                            <div class="image-profile image-profile-md">
                                <img src="{{ file_url(child['#options'].entity.user_picture.entity.fileuri) }}" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    {% endfor %}
```

So universally, how do I display the **cropped** version of the image?

The "crop API" :

[image]

Comment: What is the "cropper api" ??? Do you mean image styles? If so check this [stack questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754661/drupal-8-images-with-image-style)

Comment: It’s called the “cropper api” in drupal. Maybe I should screen capture?

Comment: 13 years of drupal dev and I've never heard of this "cropper api". Maybe provide more information on this "cropper api", A link to the module if it is a module, or maybe a screenshot of it's admin page. I always crop images with the "image styles".

Comment: Add the module names in the post.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably misunderstanding how modules [Crop API](https://www.drupal.org/project/crop) and [Image Widget Crop](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_widget_crop) work. They allow the user to crop the image manually during upload like this:
[image]

If all you want is to crop the image programmatically, you don't need the above modules. Follow these steps:

1. Go to: Admin menu > Configuration > Media > Image styles > Add image style (let's say `profile_picture`)
2. Add `Crop` effect for that style and set Width, Height, Anchor as you want
3. In your hook function:

   ```php
   use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;

   function kropotkin_preprocess_menu__account(&$variables) {
     $uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
     if ($uid > 0) {
       $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($uid);
       if (!$user->user_picture->isEmpty()) {
         $uri = $user->user_picture->entity->getFileUri();
         $picture = ImageStyle::load('profile_picture')->buildUrl($uri);
       } else {
         $picture = 'nothing here';
       }

       // Set variables
       $variables['comradery'] = [
         'profile_picture' => $picture
       ];
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: I’m not trying to programmatically crop an image, I’m just trying to retrieve the cropped image the user has created. I just don’t know where the image is stored and how to retrieve it.